# How to crop the <tr> background based on the image shape?

Tags: html, css

[image: background cropped]

How to achieve something like the above image. The below gray color  block is cropped in the middle with semi circle to accommodate the image. Should I use CSS animations or anything else to get this effect? So that the background of the below element can be cropped as per the image shape.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.

Comment: you can put border to the image -> white, no need to crop anything. use position absolute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position:absolute;` for the image icon and place it between two divs and instead of cropping you can give a `background:#fff` and padding so it looks like that.

**See code Below:**

```css
.main{
  position:relative;
  height: auto;
}
.upper {
  background: #eee;
  height: 100px;
}

.lower {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
}

img.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left:50%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="upper"></div>
  <img class="icon" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/web-and-mobile-ui-volume-24/48/1200-512.png" width="50" />
  <div class="lower"></div>
</div>
```

JsFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/75euot8d/1/

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking at.